# pycapnp: Reading and Writing a List without custom capnp file

Tags: python, capnproto

I have read through the [pycapnp quickstart](https://capnproto.github.io/pycapnp/quickstart.html) and docs, and I see no mention for how to read and write basic list objects (like a list of floats).

In particular, I am aware that if I write a custom type in a capnp file, then I can read an object of that type using something like

```
addressbook_capnp.Person.from_bytes(encoded_message)
```

What I would like to know is the syntax for reading a list of floats like this. I imagine that it would look something like

```
capnp.List.Float64.from_bytes(encoded_message)
```

But I simply can't find the correct syntax. Furthermore, since Capn Proto does not export aliases from the .capnp file, I cannot just define a list of floats there (or so it seems).

Can somebody please tell me the correct syntax for reading, writing, and creating lists of basic objects in pycapnp?

---

EDIT:

For example, in C++ I can create a list object (without a custom type) like this:

```
::capnp::MallocMessageBuilder message; 
auto capnp_point_cloud = message.initRoot<::capnp::List<Val>>(num_axes);
for (size_t i = 0; i < num_axes; ++i) { 
    capnp_point_cloud.set(i, array[i]);
}
```

Comment: There is no capnp file.

Comment: With a capnp file in place, the machinery is clear to me. Furthermore, in C++, it is relatively easy to construct a raw Capnp List of some type. I do not understand how to do this in Python

Comment: Say a list of float 64 with the values 0,1,2,3. Is that what you mean?

Comment: The issue is that I do not see how to even instantiate a raw Capnp List type in python with the custom capnp file

Comment: Ok so if I understand correctly, you want to generate a raw capnp list type in Python, create a message with an arbitrary list, then deserialize it in Python.

Comment: Yes, that is it. In C++, I know how to do this. I cannot figure this out in python though, and I cannot find anything in the docs

Comment: There are many times when we just need to send a simple list, but all of the machinery is already in place for CapnProto messages of other types

Comment: To be clear, my preference would be to have a type alias for a list, but CapnProto does not support this: https://capnproto.org/roadmap.html

Comment: It looks to me like pycapnp is built around the concept of struct schemas and although using it with raw types may be possible, you would have to use internal / undocumented parts of the implementation. I was looking at another implementation [`capnpy`](https://capnpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) but it seems that you would have the same issue.

Comment: Maybe writing a C++ module for Python would work but it sounds like a big endeavor to solve your problem.

Comment: I could certainly pybind my own implementation, but this just seems like such an obvious thing, that I thought that there must be something that exists already.

Comment: It might be worth putting the question to the author directly, see what is their take on it.